# Model not defined when using foreign key to second model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to create several relationships between some models such as User and Country. When I try to syncdb, my console outputs "Name Country is not defined".

Here is the code:

```py
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, null=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, null=False) # error here

    
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
```

Could you please help me out with this one?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Either move the class definition of `Country` on above `User`  in the file

OR

In the `User` model, update the attribute `country` to:

```
country = models.ForeignKey('Country',null=False)
```

Documentation on this can be [found here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey)

Answer (score 4):

You need to move the definition of Country above the definition of User.

What is happening is the compiler (when compiling to .pyc byte code) is compiling the Class definition for User and sees a reference to a Country type object. The compiler has not seen this definition yet and does not know what it is, hence the error of it being not defined.

So the basic rule of thumb-> Everything has to be defined before you call or reference it

Comment: No worries. I would go with karthikr's alternative method of using 'Country'. That way you don't have to move things around. I just wanted to explain how the compilation worked :)