# Simplify Django models for an eStore and assistance with ManyToManyField

Tags: python, database, django, sqlite, django-models

Building an eCommerce site that exclusively sells shirts, books, and albums to get a feel for different models. Two things that are throwing me off are:

1.) I'm not sure if I'm creating too much redundancy with my models if so how do I minimize it. For example, for music albums, I'm creating a model for albums, artists, and tracks and in each of those models I reference the other models multiple times.

2.) In regards to my ManyToManyFields, by referencing a model that's not defined until further down in models.py, `python manage.py syncdb` is throwing up an error that I have no defined the relationships. This is explained further in this SO question: [Django says my model is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17658641/django-says-my-model-is-not-defined)

Here is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models

#Artist, Album, and Tracks are tables for music albums

class Artist(models.Model):
    artist_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    short_bio = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=False, blank=False)
    albums = models.ManyToManyField(Album)
    tracks = models.ManyToManyField(Track)
    added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

class Album(models.Model):
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False, blank=False)
    artists = models.ManyToManyField(Artist)
    tracks = models.ManyToManyField(Track)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)
    added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.album_name

class Track(models.Model):
    track_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    artists = models.ManyToManyField(Artist)
    album_name = models.ManyToManyField(Album)

class AlbumImage(models.Model):
    album_name = models.ForeignKey(Album)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=False)
    main = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='albums/images/')
    added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)


#Book, BookGenre, Author tables for books

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    pages = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(BookGenre)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)
    added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Author(models.Model):
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    short_bio = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True, blank=True)
    titles = models.ManyToManyField(Book)
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(BookGenre)
    added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

class BookGenre(models.Model):
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)

class BookImage(models.Model):
    title = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=False)
    main = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='books/images/')
    added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)


#Shirt and Colors are for tables exclusively for shirts

class Shirt(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True, blank=False)
    styles = models.ManyToManyField('ShirtStyle.style')
    sz_xs = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    sz_sm = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    sz_md = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    sz_lg = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    sz_xl = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)
    added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class ShirtStyle(models.Model):
    style = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    title = models.ForeignKey('Shirt.title')

class ShirtImage(models.Model):
    title = models.ForeignKey(Shirt)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=False)
    main = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='shirts/images/')
    added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great start, but, as you've guessed, you've got a little too much redundancy in your models. I would offer the following tips:

### 1) Don't use `ManyToManyField` as much.

ManyToMany should be used where each model is related to many of the other. This isn't really the case for some of your models. For example, while each `Album` has many `Tracks`, the reverse probably isn't true; each `Track` belongs to one, and only one, `Album`. "Smells Like Teen Spirit" is a `Track` on the `Album` "Nevermind", but it's not a `Track` on any other `Album`. Thus, you should use a `ForeignKey` instead.

```
class Track(models.Model):
    track_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    album_name = models.ForeignKey(Album)
```

An exception here would be if a `Track` actually **would** be on multiple `Albums`, i.e. if it was also on a "Greatest Hits" `Album` or something in addition to "Nevermind".

### 2) Don't repeat relations

In the above example, we've connected each `Track` to a `Album` through a `ForeignKey`. We don't need to do the opposite. That is, `Album` does not need an explicit field to keep track of all of its `Tracks`. You can do that when you query. The Django docs on making queries that span relationships are [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

This also has a further implication. You'll likely be connecting your `Album` to an `Artist` through a `ForeignKey`. Because you can span relationships, you don't need to explicitly connect `Tracks` and `Artists`. Thus, a simple example of the three models should look like this:

```
from django.db import models

#Artist, Album, and Tracks are tables for music albums

class Artist(models.Model):
    artist_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    short_bio = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=False, blank=False)
    added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

class Album(models.Model):
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False, blank=False)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)
    added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.album_name

class Track(models.Model):
    track_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    album_name = models.ForeignKey(Album)
```

This is also subject to the caveat that if you'll be connecting an `Album` to multiple `Artists`, you'll need to tweak it somewhat. This would be like if you separated the band members out individually, i.e. "Abbey Road" is an `Album` for four different `Artists`: John, Paul, George, and Ringo.

### 3) Defining the model error

The problem you noted in (2) relating to models should go away once you stop repeating relations. Basically you can't use a model as a relation until you've already defined it. This was causing a problem as you were doing `ManyToMany` on **both** models to each other. One of them has to come before the other, which will result in an import problem. You could also set `null=True` if you wanted to use one before it was defined, but there's really no need in this case.

Let me know if any of this is unclear or if you have any further questions.

EDIT:

### Additional tip:

If you're going to be using `added` and `modified` fields on many models, you might want to use the `django-model-utils` package. Docs [here](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). You can subclass a `TimeStampedModel` that automatically makes `created` and `modified` fields. See [here](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/models.html#timestampedmodel).

Thus:

```
from model_utils.models import TimeStampedModel

class Artist(TimeStampedModel):
    artist_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    short_bio = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=False, blank=False)
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. This was crazy insightful, and has helped immensely in my understanding of DB schema. I've been dissecting your answer and going further down the rabbit hole reading about Django models. Two questions: 

1.) With less ForeignKey relations, I'm having trouble with admin.py, which require ForeignKeys for inline editing. How do you approach creating a one-stop interface to add artist, album, tracks, and image without altering models?

2. Your greatest hits example is why I use ManyToMany. Is it necessary still if 95% of songs are original and only 5% are covers?

Comment: @SeanDominguez: Re (1): have you tried the `InlineModelAdmin` objects? See documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects). That allows for inline model editing using Foreign Keys. If you have trouble with that, I'd recommend creating a new question, as it's hard to answer in the comments without seeing your code. As to (2): If you ever have a reason to assign one child model to multiple parents, you'll need to use ManyToMany.